# Brake issues after little accident

Tags: brakes, noise, vw, accident, handling

My car is a brand new Volkswagen Golf (2019, 7 000 km), and is equipped (among other equipments) with Autohold, it is important for the rest of the story. This system, once the car is stopped, locks the brakes until you start driving again so you don't have to press the brake pedal.

My car was completely stopped in traffic jams (and autohold was enabled), and a car hit me from behind (at approximately 20 km/h). As brakes were applied, my car did not move. The rear bumper is very damaged and the trunk is misaligned with the rest of the car.

But I noticed other problems while driving my car after the accident :

1. Autohold does not work anymore
2. Brakes are whistling (my car never made any brake noise) even if brakes are released, this is very noticeable when driving with windows opened
3. Brake pedal feels different since the accident
4. The handling of my car also feels different since the accident

I don't think the Autohold issue is a big problem, but can the 3 last problems be related to this little accident ?

My personal impression is that considerable forces were transmitted to drivetrains at the moment of impact, that could have damaged them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take it back to the shop that did the work and get them to sort these issues, the repair job is incomplete.

Hopefully, you have not waited too long since collecting the car from the repair.

If you have not had it repaired yet (not too sure from your question), then when you do take it in, you need to mention these problems so they include them on the list of work.